# Leaflet styling function to take 2 parameters

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm actually working on a leaflet map that dispays regions in different colors accordings to the lenght of the name of the region. I have the function stylings that returns a specific styling and that takes feature (from json map) as input.

```
var geojson = L.geoJson(data,{style: styling}).addTo(map);
function styling(feature) {
    return {
        fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.NAME.length),  
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'white',
        dashArray: '3',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    };
}
```

What I'm actually looking for is passing another parameter to the function styling, but I don't know how to achieve this. shall I do something like styling (,2nd Parameter) since the first parameter is retrieved automatically ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Just take two parameters to then use the second parameter in the function getColor that I modified, to do a binding of Data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a function that recall the "styling" function with the second parameter.

```
var geojson = L.geoJson(data,{style: function(feature){styling(feature, "hello")}}).addTo(map);
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/70jryouy/1/